# How can I pass both the title and an image file from my front end (React.js) to my backend API (Spring Boot)?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am attempting to make an application that allows a registered user to submit an image file (.jpeg, .png, etc) along with a title of that image. I am having trouble wrapping my mind around how to do this.

I need to send the image to an amazon AWS S3 bucket, and I was able to figure out how to do this, but adding a title input has confused me a lot in terms of how to get both the file and title from my front-end (JSON) to my back-end API and have it be saved to my post database (JPA). I have a user_post database that has the following column: ID (post ID primary key), user_id (foreign key from User table), title, & post_image (containing the file that is to be saved in the DB). So basically, I need to figure out how to get the input (both file and title) at once, send it to my back-end and save it in the Post DB.

Do I need to pass the title as an argument in my post controller? Since the UserPost DB is a one to many relationship with a User, I need to pass that logged in user's ID to my controller so that it gets sent to the post DB, I'm just not sure how.

I have been searching online everywhere for help and figured I would give Stack Overflow a shot on this as I desperately need help. I am using JWT authentication through local storage for now to access user information such as username and id. Before I was testing my API with Postman by using the "file" key in the body and then proceeding to choose the image that is to be selected, but how can I do this if I want to add a title as well? Ideally, it would be the same but with text instead of file for the type as seen below but I am not sure. (Of course depending on what key I set for the title if I am thinking of it right).

[image]

This is a screenshot of my front-end just for a visual in case it helps at all.

[image]

Here is my code, I apologize for it being so messy, I am working on cleaning it up as soon as I can. I will start with the front-end. I believe I need to set the key for my title input so that it gets passed to my back-end API, but I am not even sure if I am doing that right. I also needed to use a custom form validation since I am dealing with an image upload. I ended up putting the call to my API in my useForm.js file since my form validations are done in that custom hook.

Upload.jsx:

```js
import '../../components/pages/styles/Uploads.css';
import {Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage} from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import {clearMessage} from '../../slices/messages';
import authHeader from '../../services/auth-header';
import useForm from '../../hooks/useForm';
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/posts';

function Uploads(onUpload) {
    const {user: currentUser} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const [file, setFile] = useState();
    const [title, setTitle] = useState();
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);
    const initialValues = {
        title: '',
    };

    const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {}, []);

    const handlePost = (formValue) => {};

    const onAddImage = (file) => {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(preview);
        if (!file) return;
        setPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    };

    //The postUserImage function below was moved to useForm.js 
    //since my form validations are done there. I might have 
    //messed this up. 

    // const postUserImage = async (event) => {
    //This is the code that will get passed to my backend. I need the image and title to be added here somehow.
    //  event.preventDefault();

    //  const formData = new FormData();
    //  formData.append('file', file);
    //  formData.append('title', title);

    //  const result = await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
    //      headers: {...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    //  });
    //  console.log(result.data);
    // };

    //Custom hook call
    // const {handleChange, values, errors, handleSubmit} = useForm(postUserImage);
    const initialState = {title: ''};
    const validations = [
        ({title}) => isRequired(title) || {title: 'Title is required'},
    ];
    const {values, isValid, errors, changeHandler, submitHandler, touched} =
        useForm(initialState, validations, onUpload);

    return (
        <div className='page'>
            <div className='upload-card'>
                <div id='preview'>
                    <img
                        src={preview || require('../../assets/user-solid.jpeg')}
                        id='image'
                        alt='Thumbnail'
                        className='user-post'
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='upload-container'>
                <div className='post-form-container'>
                    <p id='upload-form-label'>Hello, feel free to post an image!</p>
                    <form
                        // onSubmit={'return Validate(this);'}

                        onSubmit={submitHandler}
                        className='upload-form'
                    >
                        <div className='panel'>
                            <div className='button_outer'>
                                <div className='btn_upload'>
                                    <input
                                        filename={file}
                                        onChange={(e) => onAddImage(e.target.files[0])}
                                        type='file'
                                        accept='.jpeg,.svg,.gif,.png'
                                        id='image-selection-btn'
                                    ></input>
                                    Choose your Art
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input
                            name='title'
                            type='text'
                            className='form-control'
                            placeholder='Enter Title'
                            id='cred-input'
                            required
                            value={values.title}
                            onChange={changeHandler}
                        />

                        {touched.title && errors.title && (
                            <p className='error'>{errors.title}</p>
                        )}

                        <button type='submit' id='post-upload-btn' disabled={isValid}>
                            Upload Image
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    function isRequired(value) {
        return value != null && value.trim().length > 0;
    }

    function isSame(value1, value2) {
        return value1 === value2;
    }
}

export default Uploads;
```

useForm.js:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {omit} from 'lodash';
import authHeader from '../services/auth-header';
import axios from 'axios';

function useForm(initialState = {}, validations = [], onSubmit = () => {}) {
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/posts';
    // Add the 'onSubmit' argument
    const {isValid: initialIsValid, errors: initialErrors} = validate(
        validations,
        initialState
    );
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState(initialErrors);
    const [isValid, setValid] = useState(initialIsValid);
    const [touched, setTouched] = useState({});
    const [file, setFile] = useState();
    const [title, setTitle] = useState();
    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        const newValues = {...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value};
        const {isValid, errors} = validate(validations, newValues);
        setValues(newValues);
        setValid(isValid);
        setErrors(errors);
        setTouched({...touched, [event.target.name]: true});
    };
    // Add this
    const submitHandler = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        onSubmit(values);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('title', values.title);

        const result = await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
            headers: {...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        });
        console.log(result.data);
    };
    return {values, changeHandler, isValid, errors, touched, submitHandler}; // Add 'submitHandler'
}

function validate(validations, values) {
    const errors = validations
        .map((validation) => validation(values))
        .filter((validation) => typeof validation === 'object');
    return {
        isValid: errors.length === 0,
        errors: errors.reduce((errors, error) => ({...errors, ...error}), {}),
    };
}

export default useForm;
```

Back-end code:

User.java:

```java
package com.Application.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table( name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),


        })

public class User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "user")
    @Column(name = "user_post")
    private Set<UserPosts> userPosts = new HashSet<>();

    public User(String username, String email
                ,String password) {

        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {

    }

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java:

```java
package com.Application.repository;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.HashTek.HashTekApplication.models.User;
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
    Boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}
```

UserPost.java:

```java
package com.Application.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_posts")
public class UserPosts {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "post_image")
    private String postImage;

    @Column(name = "likes")
    private Long likes;

    @Column(name = "views")
    private Long views;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPostImage() {
        return postImage;
    }

    public String getPostImageComplete() {
        return " https://hashtekbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/" + postImage;
    }

    public void setPostImage(String postImage) {
        this.postImage = postImage;
    }

    public Long getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(Long likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public Long getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public void setViews(Long views) {
        this.views = views;
    }
}
```

UserPostController.java:

```java
package com.Application.controller;

import com.Application.models.User;
import com.Application.models.UserPosts;
import com.Application.payload.response.MessageResponse;
import com.Application.repository.UserPostsRepository;
import com.Application.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import com.Application.security.services.CustomUserDetails;
import com.Application.security.services.CustomUserDetailsService;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.*;
import static org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.IMAGE_GIF;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/posts")
public class UserPostsController {
    private static final String AUTH_HEADER = "authorization";

    //  @Autowired
    //  private final UserPostsRepository userPostRepo;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    /**  AWS CREDENTIALS SOURCE
     For AWS Builder  **/
    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.access-key}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String accessSecret;
    @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    //    public UserPostsController(UserPostsRepository userPostRepo) {
    //        this.userPostRepo = userPostRepo;
    //    }

    @PostMapping(
        path = "/upload",
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity < ? > userPostUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        Model model,
        UserPosts userPosts, HttpServletRequest request, User user) {

        //Check if POST is empty
        if (file.isEmpty()) {

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("Please select a file to upload"));
        }

        isImage(file);

        //Hard coded bucketName -> linked to AWS
        String bucketName = "hashtekbucket";

        //Add timestamp to name to prevent duplicate names
        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();

        //getting aws access
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, accessSecret);

        //Building S3Client connection
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion(region).build();

        try {
            //            //PUSH TO BUCKET
            File fileObj = convertMultiPartFileToFile(file);
            s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, fileObj));
            fileObj.delete();
            //Show Successful Upload
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message_2", fileName + ": SuccessFully Uploaded On AWS S3");

            //JWT Token retrieval from HTTP request header
            final String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);
            String username = null;
            String jwt = null;

            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
                jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
                username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
            }

            //Load logged in Username from JWT Token obtained
            CustomUserDetails customUser = (CustomUserDetails) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            Long userId = customUser.getId();

            UserPosts myUserPost = new UserPosts();

            myUserPost.setId(userId);
            myUserPost.setPostImage(fileName);

            // The code under here is how I saved a user profile by ID,               // but I am getting an error in my post repo
            // since there is no post Id until a user creates one.

            //            //Find User by id
            //            userProfile = userProfRepo.findByUserId(userId);
            //
            //            //Set resource name to
            //            userProfile.setProfile_banner(fileName);
            //
            //            //Save database changes
            //            userProfRepo.save(userProfile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        model.addAttribute("userPosts", userPosts);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("File Upload Successful"));

    }

    private void isImage(MultipartFile file) {
        if (!Arrays.asList(
                IMAGE_JPEG.getMimeType(),
                IMAGE_SVG.getMimeType(),
                IMAGE_PNG.getMimeType(),
                IMAGE_GIF.getMimeType()).contains(file.getContentType())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("File must be an image [" + file.getContentType() + "]");
        }

    }

    /**
     File Conversion
     **/
    private File convertMultiPartFileToFile(MultipartFile file) {
        File convertedFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convertedFile)) {
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // log.error("Error converting multipartFile to file", e);
        }
        return convertedFile;
    }


}
```

If anyone could help me at all, any information, tips, or anything, it would mean the world. If I am missing anything that seems important please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> So basically, I need to figure out how to get the input (both file AND
> title) at once,

You need to send a POST request to the backend with your image and the title. It HTML 5, the standard way to do this is with a form with an input of type file

There is actually also JavaScript API to set the file input to only accept image files; I think this worked using file extension.

> send it to my backend and save it in the Post DB. Am I
> gonna need to pass the title as an argument in my post controller?

Standard file posts have the name of the file included

> Since the UserPost DB is a one to many relationship with a User, I am
> gonna need to pass that logged in user's ID to my controller so that
> it gets sent to the post DB, just not sure how.

You should not send the user id. In fact, you should typically be wary of sending the user id to the front end at all. Everything in javascript can be inspected by the user... or someone else who sits at his/her desk.

Instead you can rely on the current session (create on the backend) for user identification.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much for your response. Do you know if I would need to pass a title argument in my parameter? For example if I have a file name that is userimage.jpeg and a title  “My User Image”, how would I go about storing this into my post DB?

Comment: @StephenAranda In this case you would need to a separate input field. Depending on your case, I imagine that type = `text` or `hidden` would be the two most appropriate types for the title input

Comment: I’m sorry, if I’m asking too many questions, I truly appreciate your help. I have two inputs in my Upload.jsx. One is for the image itself which (.jpeg extension) and another input for title). I was able to figure out how to store the file name , but would I pass what a user typed as the “title”  in my controller post mapping as a parameter? Or is there a way for me to pull that somehow

Comment: `    @PostMapping(
        path = "/upload",
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity < ? > userPostUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,` I pass a key here for the file, but I just don’t know how to pass a second input that the user types into this controller method

Comment: @StephenAranda I don't know react